# How to find information about similar disks and find which is newer, last written, etc?

Tags: linux, hard-disk, administration

I have three branched copies of the same disk and I need to know when they have been used, mounted written, last file created, in order to identify and differentiate them.

I know this setup is so tedious that doesn't correspond to ask anywhere, unluckly our current state of filesystems is very prone to all this scrambling.

I already checked tune2fs but I committed the fatal error of mounting all the disks and now as you could expect, last mount and write are set to this date so I need a way to find the last time before this last.

Also I preciate any tool for comparing files in all the home directories of those drives obviously avoiding all the .conf xrowding sh*t that should be anywhere else but linux deliverately put there as there wasn't anywhere else.

Comment: How I reach this situation? I made two copies of the same disk at different times and also modifyied al of them at different times. All three have debian installed and a home directory thre's one that I use so I roughly know that it's the operative one but the other two, I'm not sure why they are there.

Comment: I was looking for that also, thanks. Also I checked the versions of all three os installalled and it happens that they are debian 8, 9 and 10 respectively. Happiliy now I have a better idea that those disks are backups of different versions of my system before sysupgrade.

Comment: However all this stuff is pretty obsolete, In these days we should have descriptions instead of labels and lots of universal metadata (record of file changes and procedence) but nobody notice this until it's too late so why to change? It seems better to add rgb leds to everything.

Comment: 'any tool for comparing files in all the home directories' - If you can mount the directories side-by-side, then `diff` can compare them, two at a time. For the file modification problem, if you have a rough estimate of the time of modification, `find -mtime` could be helpful.